# Preventing duplicate usernames in Firebase

Tags: security, firebase

I'm trying to use Firebase security rules to prevent a number of undesirable situations happening in my app. The structure I have at the moment is:

```
"usernames": {
    "twitter:123": "jack",
    "google:456": "bob"
}
```

The issue here is that I can't implement security rules such that a third user (say `facebook:789`) can't come in and hijack the username 'bob' and get access to that user's data (my data is arranged by username).

What's the accepted fix for this scenario? I've tried reversing the key/value pairs, which allows uniqueness of usernames:

```
"usernames": {
    "jack": "twitter:123",
    "bob": "google:456"
}
```

However since this doesn't enforce uniqueness of UID, any user can spam usernames - the malicious `facebook:789` could take any usernames not already taken, which would be a PITA to sort out.

Is there a way to solve this dilemma using Firebase security rules? Or is the only answer a trusted server? A trusted server would still present possible concurrency issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I've got it. Like a lot of things in Firebase, the answer lies in diligent use of denormalisation :)

This solution is still a *bit* tentative, so please don't hesitate to correct/edit/comment/answer if you have corrections or a better idea.

The username/uid pairs need to be stored in *both* formats. For lack of a better name, I've called this an *interlock*:

```
{
  "usernameInterlock" : {
    "confirm" : {
      "twitter:123" : "jack"
    },
    "request" : {
      "jack" : "twitter:123"
    }
  }
}
```

Here are the security rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "usernameInterlock": {
        "request": {
            "$username": {
              ".read": true,
              ".write": "auth.uid == newData.val()
              && !(
                data.exists()
                && root.child('usernameInterlock').child('confirm').child(data.val()).val() == $username
                )"
            }
          },
        "confirm": {
            "$uid": {
              ".read": true,
              ".write": "auth.uid == $uid 
              && root.child('usernameInterlock').child('request').child(newData.val()).val() == auth.uid"
            }
          }
    }
  }
}
```

The process is:

1. A user puts their `uid` in `/usernameInterlock/request/$desiredUsername`. This is writable *unless* `/usernameInterlock/confirm/$uid_2 == $desiredUsername` in which case it belongs to `$uid_2`. Anyone can request any usernames they want (and however many they want) because they don't mean anything unless they're under `confirm`. If someone goes too crazy this can be purged.
2. The user will then write `$desiredUsername` to `/usernameInterlock/confirm/$uid`. This can only be written to if the appropriate `request` child is already populated. This then becomes the canonical way of determining the user's username.

To verify a username, lookup `/usernameInterlock/request/$username` and then lookup the `$uid` obtained in `/usernameInterlock/confirm/$uid`, and if that value matches $username then the `($username, $uid)` is a valid pair.